# How to set that one record is marked 1 and all other 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `table Addresses` with columns `ID (PK), EmpID (int), Address (nvarchar(100), IsDefault (bit)`.
Now I have to ensure that only one record with same EmpID have IsDefault set to 1.
I have done for now following with triggers.
First one is an insert trigger. First it's checks if there is entered value 1 in `IsDefault`. If yes, then it checks if there are more then one record with same `EmpID` and `IsDefault` value set on 1. If that is also true, then it sets all other `IsDefault` values for the same `EmpID` to 0. :

```
create trigger [dbo].[TRG_dbo_Addresses_IsDefault_OnlyOneRecord_insert]
   on [dbo].[lAddressesOrganisations] 
   after insert 
as 
begin

    set nocount on;

    begin try

        if exists (
            select *
            from inserted as i
            where i.IsDefault = 1)
        begin

            if (
                select count(*)
                from dbo.Addresses as lao
                inner join inserted as i on i.ID=lao.ID
                where lao.IsDefault = 1
                    and lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
                ) > 1 
            begin

                update lao
                set lao.IsDefault = 0
                from dbo.Addresses as lao
                where (
                    select row_number () over (partition by EmpID order by ID desc) as rn
                    from dbo.Addresses as lao
                ) > 1
            end
        end
    end try

    begin catch

        if @@trancount > 0
            rollback tran;

    end catch

end
```

This other one is update trigger that I don't have a clue how to write it. First it does the same as insert trigger, checking the inserted value is 1 where value was 0. If yes, if there is more then one record with same `EmpID` and `IsDefault` set to 1. If yes,

how to write that all other records are set to 0 for same `EmpID`, while the one that is being updated remain 1?

```
create trigger [dbo].[TRG_dbo_Addresses_IsDefault_OnlyOneRecord_update]
   on [dbo].[Addresses] 
   after update 
as 
begin

    set nocount on;

    begin try

        if exists (
            select *
            from inserted as i
            inner join deleted as d on d.ID=i.ID
            where i.IsDefault = 1
                and d.IsDefault = 0)
        begin
            if (
                select count(*)
                from dbo.Addresses as lao
                inner join inserted as i on i.ID=lao.ID
                where lao.IsDefault = 1
                    and lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
                ) > 1 
            begin
                update lao
                set lao.IsDefault = 0
                from dbo.Addresses as lao
                inner join inserted as i on i.ID=lao.ID
                where (I don't have an idea what to put here)
                    and lao.OrganisationID = i.OrganisationID
            end
        end
    end try

    begin catch

        if @@trancount > 0
            rollback tran;

    end catch

end
```

I'm working on ms sql 2016.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour here? Is it "any other defaults get magically set to 0", as you have currently implemented, or "at most one row per empid can be set to 1"? If it's the latter, and producing an error is acceptable instead of changing other data, it can be implemented via a filtered index.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever: All then one record per EmpID. I can have u multiple EmpID in a table, but only one can have a IsDefault set to one. All other must be 0. It will be possible to change default address for same EmpID. So I can not use index cause I want be able to change IsDefault value on some other Address for same EmpID.

Comment: So you *do* want the "magically change other rows" behaviour? (Because obviously the index works fine if you first unset the current default and then set a new default)

Comment: yes. I want it to get change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Matt: if possible, avoid trigger.

Anyway, I think in your UPDATE trigger you should change to:

```
         if (
            select count(*)
            from dbo.Addresses as lao
            inner join inserted as i on lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
            where lao.IsDefault = 1                     
            ) > 1 
        begin
            update lao
            set lao.IsDefault = 0
            from dbo.Addresses as lao
            inner join inserted as i on lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
            where  lao.IsDefault = 1
                and lao.ID <> i.id
        end
```

Morevore, you can rewrite it to:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM 
          FROM dbo.Addresses as lao 
          INNER join inserted as i on lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
          WHERE lao.IsDefault = 1   AND lao.ID <>i.ID)           
          BEGIN
                UPDATE lao
                SET lao.IsDefault = 0
                FROM dbo.Addresses as lao
                INNER JOIN inserted as i on lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
                WHERE lao.IsDefault = 1
                    and lao.ID <> i.id
          END
```

You should change your insert trigger too.

**Updated: insert trigger.**
As far I can see (but I can't do tests, so please do complete case tests), and if ID is always max value or if you want to preserve default of last id inserted, I think you could rewrite your insert trigger as following: (you could remove IF too, if you don't care about doing always an UPDATE for zero rows too)

```
as 
begin    
    set nocount on;    
    begin try
       IF EXISTS(SELECT 1  
          FROM dbo.Addresses as lao 
          INNER join inserted as i on lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
          WHERE lao.IsDefault = 1 
                AND lao.ID <>i.ID
                AND i.IsDefault=1)           
          BEGIN
                UPDATE lao
                SET lao.IsDefault = 0
                FROM dbo.Addresses as lao
                INNER JOIN inserted as i on lao.EmpID = i.EmpID
                WHERE lao.IsDefault = 1
                    and lao.ID <> i.id
                    AND i.IsDefault=1
          END
end try
begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0
        rollback tran;
end catch
```

This  change (AND i.IsDefault=1) could be applied to UPDATE trigger too.

Comment: As I answer to Matt: If there is any other way then triggers, let me know. I'm not into triggers also, but can't find out how to do it without them cause I have to change the values in fields on update.

Comment: And please, if you can tell me, what is wrong in my insert trigger? Or do you only mean that it's better to rewrite it to if exists?

Comment: I think you should remove in insert trigger "on i.ID=lao.ID" and use the same as I wrote for UPDATE trigger (then you can choose to use COUNT or EXISTS), but I think you join clause should be modified.

Comment: Column ID that you are inserting is always higher value?

Comment: Yes. ID column is always higher. Its a Identity 1,1.

Answer (score 0):

I might consider whether the problem that you are trying to solve here could be solved without a trigger. Triggers tend to carry significant performance penalties and can separate logic from the rest of your code, making it a headache to maintain in the future.

If you really want to go with a trigger solution on row insert/update and there is always exactly 1 row marked with the bit, don't try to calculate counts of rows with it. Simply set all rows to 0 for the relevant EmpID and then update the inserted row to 1 after that in the trigger.

Comment: If there is any other way then triggers, I'm here to listen. I was thinking that it's not possible to do that without triggers.